# Error uploading S3 Object with Server Side Encryption using Amazon KMS

Tags: java, encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting the following exception when trying to reproduce the sample code Amazon provides for uploading S3 objects to be server side encrypted using Amazon KMS (key management service):

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: please use region-specific endpoint to access buckets located in regions that require V4 signing.
:: 
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument;
```

The code used is:

```
public void uploadServerSideEncryptedFileToS3( String bucketName , String key , String sourceFilePath , String masterKey ) {

    awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey );
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest( bucketName,
                key , new File( sourceFilePath ) ).withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams( new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams( masterKey ) );

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProtocol( Protocol.HTTPS );

    AmazonS3 connection = new AmazonS3Client( awsCredentials , clientConfiguration );
    connection.setRegion( com.amazonaws.regions.Region.getRegion( Regions.US_EAST_1 ) );
    PutObjectResult response = connection.putObject( putObjectRequest );
}
```

Comment: I think the error is saying that you are using the wrong region, you're hardcoding US_EAST_1 when it might be expecting something else apparently. I'm guessing you're not on the US east coast.

Comment: Everything I've done to date has been in US East region (my S3 buckets, my EC2 buckets, and any other endpoints used)

Comment: maybe need clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride("AWSS3V4SignerType");

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I used for S3 upload

```
    @Test
public void testNoMetaData() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
    amazonS3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(region));

    byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm());
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, inputStream, metadata);

    putObjectRequest.withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(awsKmsKeyId));
    amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Where is awsKmsKeyId ?